# div does not react under circumstances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm doing a website for a friend of mine and I have some really wierd behaviur here, which I totally cannot understand.

main navigation

- about
- pictures
- videos
- files
- contanct

in pictures and in videos, there are categorys, when you switch between the categorys, the title of the current catgeory is loaded in a DIV with the id **contentRowTitle**

```
$("#contentContainer").delegate(".catBit", "click", function() {
  var catID = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
  var pwd = $(this).attr('data-pwd');   
  var catType = $(this).attr('data-type'); 

  $('#contentRowTitle').slideUp(function() {
    $('.thumbContainer').fadeOut(function() {
      if(pwd != "") {
        $('#loginRow').show();              
        $('#contentRowTitle').load('./'+catType+'/contentImagesHeader?id='+catID, function() {
            $('#contentRowTitle').slideDown();            
        });

      } else {

        $('#contentRowTitle').slideUp('slow', function() {     

            $('#contentRowTitle').load('./'+catType+'/contentHeader?id='+catID, function(responseText) {                  alert(responseText);  
                $('#contentRowTitle').slideDown();                    
            });
        });
      }

      $('.thumbContainer').load('./'+catType+'/contentImages?id='+catID, function() {            
        $('.thumbContainer').fadeIn();   
        //$('#thumbContainer').slideDown();            
      });
    });     
  });  

});
```

now everyhting seems to work fine.. BUT if you go to pictrures, and click on some thumbnails

(this is the function that is beeingexecuted when you click on some thumbs in a category)

```
$(".contentBox").delegate(".imgPreview", "click", function() { 
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 

    $('#wrap').fadeOut(function() {
       $('#showDetailLoader').fadeIn(function() {
           $('.galMainImg').attr('data-id', id);
           $('#showDetail').load('./gal/show?id='+id, function() {
               $('#showDetailLoader').fadeOut(function() {
                   $('#showDetail').fadeIn();
                   $('.galTitle').textillate({ in: { effect: 'flipInY' } });

                    $.getJSON('./gal/statsAdd?id='+id, function( data ) {  
                    });
               });
           });
       }); 
    });
});
```

.. and now you go to videos and switch between the categorys... the DIV `contentRowTitle` does not react to anything.. I have put an alert inside the `load()` callback and it shows up.. but why does the output of the load-URL not show up in the DIV ???

Comment: in the load callback, the function is called with arguments, the first of which is `responseText` - console.log that, is it what you expect?

Comment: `in a DIV with the id contentRowTitle` - I hope the ID is unique (as all ID's are in your HTML should be)

Comment: Where is your code to bind a click handler to `#contentRowTitle`?

Comment: @JaromandaX .. Hi, the load-callback responses the output it should.. it is HTML code what comes back.. also, the IDs are all unique

Comment: @Barmar .. the click-handler is bind in on a parent DIV.. as I load the content asychronously, I have to delegate.. `$("#contentContainer").delegate(".catBit", "click", function() { ..`

Comment: FYI, `.delegate` is deprecated, you should use `.on`

Comment: The question says that the problem is with `#contentRowTitle`, not `.catBit`.

Comment: I now found out, that the reason for the DIVs not reacting is that there are somehow 2 requests made ..oO

... but I really don't get it why there are 2 requests.